# Insert data to table

Tags: php, sql, sugarcrm

I have custom module.
I want to insert data based on query from another module.
I have used below code.

```
function DuplicateReport()
{
    $dup_report = new dp_Duplicate_Data();
    $sql = "SELECT count(id) as cnt from contacts INNER JOIN (SELECT first_name,last_name,count(*) as rows FROM `contacts` where deleted = 0 GROUP BY first_name,last_name HAVING count(rows) > 1) as p where contacts.deleted=0 AND p.`first_name` = contacts.`first_name` and p.`last_name` = contacts.`last_name`";
    $result = $GLOBALS['db']->query($sql);
    $dup_name_no = mysql_num_rows($result); 
    $dup_report->contact_name = $dup_name_no;
    $dup_report->save();
}
```

However not getting inserted.Pls Help.

Comment: In this code there is no insert so you cannot insert anything to DB. You should show more code

Comment: Why do you set the number of returned rows into contact name?
To debug databse query: Try to get the insert query (I think that is generated by `$dup_report->save();`) and run it directly on database. The returned error message will help you to fix the problem.